# Code being skipped over in node async fs.readFile

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image]

I'm trying to store an array of objects , with each object containing an array and an index (called 'column'). the column is string that looks like

```
'0:lubbock:LW8-12$'
```

In the main file I am calling:

```
const tbdObj = await myFunctions.getFromStorageBy(mycolumn);
```

I want to search through the json in the file 'storage.json' for the object that matches the index (there should be only 1).

```
async function getFromStorageBy(index) {
  let match;
  fs.readFile("storage.json", function (err, data) {
    // Display the file content
    // console.log(index);
    const jsonArray = JSON.parse(data);
    const matches = jsonArray.filter(obj => obj.column == index);
    console.log('matches');
    console.log(matches);
    match = matches.pop();
    console.log(match);
  });
    return match;
}
```

The program appears to skip over the readfile block and match is undefined when I try to return it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `fs.readFile()` is asynchronous. You're not waiting for it to finish before you do `return match`

Comment: Use `fs.readFileSync()` instead.

Comment: Why is `getFromStorageBy` an `async` function? You’re not using `await` in it.

Comment: @SebastianSimon - I'm relatively new to node and async/await. I was using async because the main.js calls this function within an async block